# Namespace in Code Behinde and ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, code-behind

i designed web page and put controls in it , then i added name space to code behind file and add

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="RegisterName" %>
```

to asp file and

```
   namespace RegisterName
   {
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
```

now i have some Error :

```
Error   4   'ASP.default_aspx' does not implement interface member 'System.Web.IHttpHandler.IsReusable'
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions or warnings?

Comment: @Magnus Eklund: web site

Comment: after handling controls solved , `Error 1 Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).` appear !

Comment: @Erwin :  warning and project not compiled

Answer (score 2):

You need both the page and the code-behind to be parts of the *same* namespace.

By adding the `namespace` declaration to the code-behind, it and the web page are now in different namespaces.

Additionally, the `@Import` page directive simply means that you can access types declared in the imported namespace, not that the page belongs to it.

You need to ensure that the `@Page` directive matches the fully qualified name of the code-behind class.